# Replacing specific column and row names

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to replace the first column  (eg. empty cell, followed by 110, 111, 210, etc. ) and first row  (eg. empty cell, followed by 110, 111, 210, etc. ) with specific characters - for example, 111 I would like to change to A, and 310 to B. There is no relationship between A and B they denote characters. Additionally when using `rename()`, if one column name is missing the replacement is not carried out (e.g. 1111 with B, but since 1111 is missing,  111 and 310 are not replaced). How can I avoid this?

Original data:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Sample data:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(110, 111, 210, 310, 1000, 1100, 1110, 1120
), `110` = c(NA, 0, 0.003552398, 0, 0, 0, 9.54e-05, 0), `111` = c(0.008264463, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `210` = c(0.008264463, 0, 0.687388988, 
0.135135135, 0, 0.019230769, 0.014408397, 0.01369863), `310` = c(0, 
0, 0.006216696, 0.405405405, 0, 0, 0.00028626, 0), `1000` = c(0, 
0, 0.000888099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `110` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `111` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `210` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `310` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `1000` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: @Ronak many thanks, doesn't matter the name or order - I will allocate name specific names (eg. "MeasureOne" or "AfterMeasdure 1")

Comment: your first row and first col seems colnmames and rownames respectively?

Comment: @AniGoyal exactly!!! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need this?

First 1-2 steps are done only to create dataframe like yours and are thus, not needed.

```r
xx <- structure(list(X1 = c(110, 111, 210, 310, 1000, 1100, 1110, 1120
), `110` = c(NA, 0, 0.003552398, 0, 0, 0, 9.54e-05, 0), `111` = c(0.008264463, 
                                                                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `210` = c(0.008264463, 0, 0.687388988, 
                                                                                                  0.135135135, 0, 0.019230769, 0.014408397, 0.01369863), `310` = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                   0, 0.006216696, 0.405405405, 0, 0, 0.00028626, 0), `1000` = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0, 0.000888099, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), spec = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "collector")), `110` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "collector")), `111` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "collector")), `210` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "collector")), `310` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "collector")), `1000` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

library(tibble) 
xx <- xx %>% column_to_rownames('X1')
#your array is something like this
xx
#>              110         111         210         310        1000
#> 110           NA 0.008264463 0.008264463 0.000000000 0.000000000
#> 111  0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
#> 210  0.003552398 0.000000000 0.687388988 0.006216696 0.000888099
#> 310  0.000000000 0.000000000 0.135135135 0.405405405 0.000000000
#> 1000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
#> 1100 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.019230769 0.000000000 0.000000000
#> 1110 0.000095400 0.000000000 0.014408397 0.000286260 0.000000000
#> 1120 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.013698630 0.000000000 0.000000000

library(tidyverse)
dimnames(xx) <- map(dimnames(xx), ~ case_when(.x == '111' ~ 'A',
                              .x == '310' ~ 'B',
                              TRUE ~ .x))
xx
#>              110           A         210           B        1000
#> 110           NA 0.008264463 0.008264463 0.000000000 0.000000000
#> A    0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
#> 210  0.003552398 0.000000000 0.687388988 0.006216696 0.000888099
#> B    0.000000000 0.000000000 0.135135135 0.405405405 0.000000000
#> 1000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
#> 1100 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.019230769 0.000000000 0.000000000
#> 1110 0.000095400 0.000000000 0.014408397 0.000286260 0.000000000
#> 1120 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.013698630 0.000000000 0.000000000
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>